# SQL "Incorrect syntax near ','"

Tags: sql, sql-server

So this is the code:

```
create procedure udp_import_oltp_data
as
    truncate table customer_stg
    insert into customer_stg
    (
        customer_no,
        customer_name,
        customer_address,
        po_address,
        zip_code,
        city,
        region,
        country
    )
    select (customerid, cust_name, (street_no + ' ' + street_name), po_address, zip, town_city, area, country) from [1385651_OLTP].dbo.customer
```

The comma after "customerid" is the one it's talking about, and I've also got it for the close bracket after "country". I've done some searching but can't find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use parenthesis around select column list. It should be:

```
select customerid, cust_name, (street_no + ' ' + street_name), po_address, zip, town_city, area, country 
from ...
```

Comment: Thanks! Now I feel really dumb lol. Guess it's just one of those days.

Answer (score 3):

Its because of the parenthesis in select query. We won't use parenthesis for select query.